# How to stop Black from removing new lines in function call args?

Tags: python, pep8, python-black

I want to document an external function:

```
strange_function(
    # Comments about what this argument does
    param_1=True,

    # Comments about what this argument does
    param_2=False,
)
```

Black reformats it as:

```
strange_function(
    # Comments about what this argument does
    param_1=True,
    # Comments about what this argument does
    param_2=False,
)
```

I *want* the new line between `param_1` and `param_2` because comments are more readable that way. But black removes this. How do it stop it from doing so?

Comment: Isn't the entire idea behind black that it's uncompromising and won't let you decide on fomratting etc?

Comment: It has some options.

Comment: When commenting arguments i would rather recommend using a multiline docstring instead of embedding it like that

Comment: Agreew with @tbjorch, this is quite unreadable. An interested reader of that function might be interested in the signature of the function. Seperate signature and documentation! For documentation of functions and its arguements see [Python Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

Black is very unforgiving, giving you only a single knob to turn: how many characters per line to allow.